# Program calculating power of 2

Tags: java, math, loops

I'm writing a simple program to calculate power of 2. A user would enter the number of times they want to calculate the power of 2, let say the user enter 4, my program would returns 2,4,8,16.Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PowersOf2

{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

int numPowersOf2;        
//How many powers of 2 to compute

int nextPowerOf2 = 1;    
//Current power of  2

int exponent = 0;            

//Exponent for current power of 2 -- this

//also serves as a counter for the loop

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many powers of 2 would you like printed?");
        numPowersOf2 = scan.nextInt();

        //print a message saying how many powers of 2 will be printed
        //initialize exponent -- the first thing printed is 2 to the what?

    System.out.println("Here are the first " + numPowersOf2 + " power of 2");


      while (exponent<numPowersOf2)
        {
          //print out current power of 2

            nextPowerOf2=nextPowerOf2*2;

            exponent++;

            System.out.println(nextPowerOf2);
            //find next power of 2 -- how do you get this from the last one?

            //increment exponent
             }
        }
}
```

If I want it to start at 0 first say like 2^0=1, so if user enter 4, it would give back 1,2,4,8 instead of 2,4,8,16. How do I modify this to get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just print `nextPowerOf2` before you change it.

```
while (exponent<numPowersOf2)
{
    System.out.println(nextPowerOf2);

    nextPowerOf2=nextPowerOf2*2;
    exponent++;
}
```

Comment: Yea I've thought and tried that but the output became 1 2 2 4 4 8 8 and so forth

Comment: Thanks, i've got it, i had two println statement in the code thats why.

Comment: @Tuan: yup, that would do it :)

Answer (score 5):

2<sup>n</sup> == (1 << n); 0 <= n < 32

Answer (score 1):

You should ONLY print the value before multiplying by 2.

```
 //print out current power of 2
 System.out.println(nextPowerOf2);
 nextPowerOf2=nextPowerOf2*2;
 exponent++;
```

Comment: If i printed the value first then it would double printed the computed value

Comment: Yes i've got it, I had another println in there and forgot to take it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First print, then update. Just a reordering of operations:

```
while (exponent<numPowersOf2)
{
    //print out current power of 2
    System.out.println(nextPowerOf2);

    //find next power of 2
    nextPowerOf2=nextPowerOf2*2;

    //increment exponent
    exponent++;
}
```

Now with correct indentation and comments in sensible places, too!

Incidentally, it makes more sense to write this with a `for` loop:

```
for (int exponent = 0; exponent < numPowersOf2; ++exponent) {
    //print out current power of 2
    System.out.println(nextPowerOf2);

    //find next power of 2
    nextPowerOf2=nextPowerOf2*2;
}
```

Comment: If i did what u told me, the output becomes this Here are the first 4 power of 2
1
2
2
4
4
8
8

Comment: I bet you didn't do what I told you, then. You probably have two `println` calls in the loop body.

Comment: Yes got it, i did have two println statement. Thanks

Comment: A `for` loop is just syntactic sugar for a `while` loop: `for (a; b; c) { d; }` is exactly the same (apart from scoping) as `a; while (b) { d; c; }`.

Comment: Could you tell me why it works when we print first then do the math. I always thought if I printed first it will give the 1 and the still 2,4,8,16 instead of just 1,2,4,8

Comment: It works because you initialize the variables to the right values. We print before we change anything, so `exponent` is still 0, and `nextPowerOf2` is still 1. And indeed, 2^0 = 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 nextPowerOf2 = 1;
 exponent     = 0;
 do
 {
     System.out.println(nextPowerOf2);
     nextPowerOf2=nextPowerOf2*2;
     exponent++;
 }
 while( exponent < numPowersOf2 );
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these? They are quite fast and fit most needs previous, current, and next.

EDIT: noticed you wanted it to print out all, well what you could do is where the while loop's are add a print out.

```
public static int getPowerOfTwo(int size)
{
    int n = -1;
    while (size >> ++n > 0);
    return (1 << n - 1 == size) ? size : 1 << n;
}

public static int getNextPowerOfTwo(int size)
{
    int n = -1;
    while (size >> ++n > 0);
    return 1 << n;
}

public static int getPreviousPowerOfTwo(int size)
{
    int n = -1;
    while (size >> ++n > 0);
    return 1 << n - 1;
}
```

Just in case you can't figure it out the below should work.

```
public static void displayNextPowersOfTwo(int size)
{
    int n = -1;
    while (size >> ++n > 0) {
         System.out.print((1 << n) + ",");
    }
    System.out.print('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int numpowerof2 = 4, nextpower0f2 = 2, exponent = 0;
while(exponent < numpowerof2) {
  System.out.println(nextpower0f2);
  nextpower0f2 = nextpower0f2 * 2;
  exponent++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of using :**

```
while (exponent < numPowersOf2)
```

**Use This:**

```
while (exponent <= numPowersOf2)

// <= will start with 0, which is 2^0=1
```